# What does どうしてする mean?

Tags: meaning

The full sentence I've found in my flashcards:

> これはどうしてするのですか。

The given translation is

> How should one do [go about (doing)] this?

Could you please explain the どうしてする part more literally? Why not simply どうする?

Can't find the phrase through google though, could be just ungrammatical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「これはどうしてするのですか。」

「どうして」 here means the same thing as 「どうやって」("***in what manner***", "***using what method***", etc.).

Thus, as the given translation says, the sentence means:

> "How should one do [go about (doing)] this?"

If you want a really raw, literal translation, it would be:

> "As for this, in what manner, does one do?"

which is why the TL your falshcards give you is very good.

> Why not simply どうする?

Because that would mean a completely different thing.

> 「これは**どうする**のですか。」 means:
>
> "What should we/you/one do with this?"

The 「どう」 in 「どうする」 means "what" rather than "how", which is a common mistake among Japanese-learners.

Finally, not to confuse you, the original sentence in question 「これはどうしてするのですか。」 can also mean "Why do you/we (have to) do this?" because 「どうして」 can also mean 「なぜ」.  As usual, which one the sentence means depends entirely on the context.